# Docker offline network

Tags: docker, networking, offline

How can I create network without connect to internet?

I have 2 docker networks offline and online and i need disable internet connection for all containers in my offline network

[image]

And I have docker-compose file like that

```
some_offline_container:
    build:
      context: ./offline/first-container
    networks:
      - offline
 networks:
    online:
    offline:
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind accepting my answer if it helped you?

Comment: @YannicHamann yep, I already liked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the [internal](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#options) flag sufficient for your use case?

When you specify this option you create a network that doesn’t allow access to communicate with external networks. In the following example, you would have an isolated network called `my_internal_network` without internet access.

```
version: '3'
services:
  h1:
    image: "httpd"
    networks:
      - my_internal_network
  h2:
    image: "httpd"
    networks:
      - my_internal_network
  h3:
    image: "httpd"
    networks:
      - my_network
networks:
  my_internal_network:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true  # restrict external access to the network
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Be advised, using an internal network does currently not allow any access to exposed ports between containers. Which renders many scenarios for internal network useless.